# JList have some troubles with indexes so i cant remove items

Tags: java, jlist

i created a GUI with an ADD and REMOVE button to save items to a JList. The add button works perfectly but when i want to remove something i stumble across a problem. My remove button works like this, when i press it, i get the selected index that i have marked and removes the item at the index. My problem is that when i press the item i want to remove and then hit REMOVE it doesnt save the index and it just returns -1 which tells me that no index has been marked. Any tips how i work around this?

```
 private void removeProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    productList.getModel();
    int selectedIndex = productList.getSelectedIndex();

    if(selectedIndex != -1){

        listModel.remove(selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your JList is setup correctly?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    model.addElement("1");
    model.addElement("2");
    model.addElement("3");
    model.addElement("4");

    JList<String> test = new JList<>(model);
    test.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    test.setSelectedIndex(2);

    System.out.println("items before removal");
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
        System.out.println(model.getElementAt(i));
    }

    int selectedIndex = test.getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIndex > 0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("removing item at index %d : %s", selectedIndex, model.getElementAt(selectedIndex)));
        model.remove(selectedIndex);
    }

    System.out.println("items after removal");
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
        System.out.println(model.getElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is correctly. If i by example just remove the first item on index 0 "listModel.remove(0);" when pressing the button it works perfectly. So i'm sure that the index isnt saved when hitting the REMOVE button and i cant figure out a way to go around this

Comment: try attaching a list selection listener and add some debug logging to it (print selected indexes etc.) check that the selection mode is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So i did find a solution, i dont know if it was the best but it is working.
If anyone finds anything which will be better just post it.

What i've done is i'm using a listselectionlistener and when a item is pressed its saves the index into a global variable which my REMOVE button reads the value from.

```
    private void indexListener() {
    ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
            productList.getModel();
            selectedIndex = listSelectionEvent.getFirstIndex();


        }

    };
    productList.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);

}
```